# How can I deploy a Next.js App to Netlify?

Tags: next.js, netlify, netlify-function

I am currently facing an issue with my Next.js app deployment. After following a guide from netlify’s blog on how to create Server-side rendered App using netlify for Next.js, I was able to have a successful build but my site seems not to be working.

The site is currently at https://sleepy-murdock-8d5427.netlify.app/. The error message will be pasted below.

```
{
"errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
"errorMessage": "FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/api/notes failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000",
"trace": [
"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/api/notes failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000",
"    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
"    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)",
"    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)",
"    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"
]
}
```

Comment: Netlify doesn't support server-side rendered next.js apps. Which guide did you follow?

Comment: https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/06/10/2-ways-to-create-server-rendered-routes-using-next.js-and-netlify/ This one.

Answer (score 3):

Netlify can serve only static webpages. **I do not recommend serving ssr apps on netlify for this reason.** -> It will create your ssr app to a static webpage. Because of this most of the next.js functions like `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` would not work.
You need to have *functions* for that.

To serve a serve-side-rendering app on netlify, you have to **build and export** every page.

To do that, I added these lines to my `package.json` file.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build: "next build",
    "export": "next export",
    "deploy": "npm run build && npm run export"
  }
}
```

You site should be live and rendered as a static application when you **deploy it to netlify**.